# iOS System Timestamp - C# Monotouch/Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, timestamp, system

I need to synchronize some data that is captured simulataneously on multiple iphones.

**Question**

1. Does iOS have a system timestamp field (or similar)?
2. If so, does every iphone in the same timezone/area/region etc. have EXACTLY the same time? i.e. Is it based on a particular clock or from an Apple server?
3. If not, is there anyway that I can ensure that two pieces of data, that are both captured on separate iPhones, can be stamped with the same timestamp at the point of beginning the data capture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime.UtcNow will get you the current UTC time.

Most devices will sync their time based on the wireless carrier.  Otherwise there is a system option to automatically sync time that is presumably using an NTP server.

Depending on what kind of granularity you need, this may be good enough.

Comment: Thanks. So if I execute "DateTime.UtcNow" simulataneously on two separate iphones, it should provide the same value? Or only if they are on the same carrier? I guess I need to write a test case....

Comment: Yes, they should be the same, within some margin of error.  But there are probably edge cases where they won't be (ie, an iPad that has time sync turned off, or a device in Airplane mode, etc).  You'll have to decide if those are worth worrying about or not.